# Subquery problems

Tags: sql

I have two tables, Catch and Members. It´s af fishing club website.
I want to make at list showing name, weight, Spiecies. But only the top weight for each spiecies, like a rekord list. The two tables looks like this.

Members:

> - MemberID
> - Firstname
> - Secondname

Catch:

> - MemberID(FK)
> - Spiecies
> - weight

This shows only name and weight, i can´t get Spiecies shown.

```
SELECT  
CONCAT(Firstname, ' ' ,Secondname) AS 'Name',
Allcatch.Rekord
FROM Members
JOIN
(SELECT 
MAX(Weight) AS 'Rekord', MemberID
FROM Catch 
GROUP BY MemberID) AS Allcatch
ON Allcatch.MemberID = Members.MemberID;  
-- ORDER BY Allcatch.Weight DESC
```

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some product specific functions there.)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  
CONCAT(Firstname, ' ' ,Secondname) AS 'Name',
Allcatch.Rekord, Allcatch.Spiecies
From Members
INNER JOIN Catch ON Catch.MemberID = Members.MemberID
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
max(Weight) AS 'Rekord', Spiecies
FROM Catch 
GROUP BY Spiecies) AS Allcatch ON Allcatch.Rekord = Catch.Weight AND  Allcatch.Spiecies = Catch.Spiecies
```

.

Comment: I says.
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Allcatch' in 'field list'

Comment: Name  Weight  Spiecies
Henrik     4.4      Cod
Thomas   3.6      Cod

I want only one weigt for each spiecies. It shows all three columns, but the same Spiecies more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

I have framed the below query using row_number() function with respect to `oracle` syntax.

```
SELECT  
Firstname||Secondname AS 'Name',
Allcatch.Rekord,
Allcatch.Spiecies
From Members
JOIN
(SELECT 
Weight, MemberID, Spiecies,row_number() over (partition by MemberID order by Weight desc) as rn FROM Catch) AS Allcatch
ON Allcatch.MemberID = Members.MemberID
where Allcatch.rn = 1;
```

Comment: It cant understand OVER
I use Mysql Workbench

Comment: Ok. Please tag `mysql` in the question